# Passing data-attribute from Vue instance html tag

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to declare and pass a data-attribute value from a html tag of the Vue instance, and then have it available in the data object?

index.html:

```
<div id="app" data-title="My app title"></div>
```

App.vue:

```
data () {
  return {
    appTitle: // whatever is declared in data-title
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

*index.html*:

```html
<div id="app" data-id="123"></div>
```

*index.js*:

```js
(function (el) {

    new Vue({
        el,
        render: h => h(Module),
        data: () => Object.assign({}, el.dataset) ,
    });

})(document.getElementById('app'));
```

*Module.vue*:

```js
export default {
    name: 'Module',
    data() {
        return {
            id: this.$parent.id,
        };
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is:

```
data () {
  return {
    appTitle: document.getElementById('app').dataset.title
  }
}
```

However, it is possible that the DOM is not available on component initialization. So you should probably put that code into the mounted hook of your component:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                appTitle: null
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.appTitle = document.getElementById('app').dataset.title
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Even if I declare the `data-title` tag, it is reset when Vue renders. So this returnes undefined.

Comment: I see - it's probably because of my structure. I have my Vue init inside a separate main.js file - and rest is done in App.vue

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach that doesn't rely on the DOM API, but cannot be used to get data-attributes from the root (#app) element:

```
{
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div ref="mydiv" data-attribute="data attribute">
            Hello from template
            <div>
                Hello from {{attribute}}
            </div>
        </div>`,
    data(){
        return {
          attribute: ''
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$data.attribute = this.$refs.mydiv.dataset.attribute;
    }
});
```

[Here's a pen with a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMpwEg)